# new Apache Geronimo v3.0 Runtime warning

Tags: php, eclipse, apache, geronimo

When I am creating a new Apache Geronimo v3.0 Runtime on Eclipse, it warns me "Apache Geronimo v3.0 requires JRE version 6 or higher." In fact, I have installed jre1.8.0_121. What should I do to fix it?